# Python 3; Using "itertools.permutations" and a list of 4 digit codes to generate all 6 digit permutations?

Tags: python, python-itertools

So here is what I want to achieve:
I have an input-file which is a .txt-file containing 4 digit codes, one 4 digit code per line

Ex. "input.txt":

`1234`

Now I want to all possible permutations for each entry in the list written to an output-file (.txt).

In my example above my output-file has 24 rows which makes sense since 4^4 = 24.

However what I want is to get all permutations for each entry in the list as 6 digits instead of 4 digits.

So for '1234' there should be combinations such as this:

```
X1234X 
1X234X
12X34X
```

etc.
where "X" are digits between 0-9.

I asked ChatGPT since I'm not a programmer myself and received the following code (see below):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from itertools import permutations
import os
import datetime

class PermutationGenerator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Permutation Generator")
        self.input_file = ""
        self.output_file = ""

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Label(self.master, text="Input File:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
        tk.Label(self.master, text="Output File:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")

        self.input_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=50, state="readonly")
        self.output_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=50, state="readonly")

        self.input_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.output_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        tk.Button(self.master, text="Browse", command=self.browse_input).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        tk.Button(self.master, text="Browse", command=self.browse_output).grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        tk.Button(self.master, text="Generate Permutations", command=self.generate_permutations).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.master, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
        self.progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)

    def browse_input(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
        if file_path:
            self.input_entry.config(state="normal")
            self.input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.input_entry.insert(0, file_path)
            self.input_entry.config(state="readonly")
            self.input_file = file_path

    def browse_output(self):
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
        if file_path:
            self.output_entry.config(state="normal")
            self.output_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.output_entry.insert(0, file_path)
            self.output_entry.config(state="readonly")
            self.output_file = file_path

    def generate_permutations(self):
        if not self.input_file or not self.output_file:
            tk.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please select input and output files.")
            return

        with open(self.input_file, 'r') as infile:
            input_data = infile.read().splitlines()

        total_permutations = len(input_data) * factorial(4, 6)
        self.progress_bar["maximum"] = total_permutations

        log_filename = f"{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]}_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d%H%M')}.log"
        log_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), log_filename)

        with open(log_filepath, 'w') as logfile:
            logfile.write(f"Permutation generation log - {datetime.datetime.now()}\n\n")

            for entry in input_data:
                for perm in permutations(entry, 6):
                    permutation_str = ''.join(perm)
                    with open(self.output_file, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(permutation_str + '\n')

                    logfile.write(f"Generated: {permutation_str}\n")
                    self.progress_bar.step(1)
                    self.master.update()

        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Permutations generated successfully.")
        self.progress_bar["value"] = 0

def factorial(base, length):
    return base ** length

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = PermutationGenerator(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

In my question to ChatGPT I asked it to create a GUI and a log file in addition to the core functionality.

Now I can browse to an input-file and specify an output-file but when I click "Generate permutations" I instantly receive "Permutations generated successfully!" but the specified output-file is empty.
Also it instantly returns the "Success..."-message so I guess it doesn't actually do anything even though it reports "Success...".

Why doesn't it work?

[Image of the GUI showing success while the output-file is actually empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8AV1.png)

Best Regards

Comment: as an fyi, ChatGPT is not good at producing correct solutions imo.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem with your code

A lot of the code you have posted is about generating the GUI, which isn't really relevant to this problem.

This is the bit with the actual logic for solving the problem (but I've added comments to explain what's happening):

```py
# loop through every line in the input
for entry in input_data:
    
    # find all the permutations of the line where the length is 6
    for perm in permutations(entry, 6):

        # `perm` is a tuple of digits, so concatenate them all together
        permutation_str = ''.join(perm)

        # write that new permutation to a file
        with open(self.output_file, 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(permutation_str + '\n')
```

The problem with this is that's not what `permutations` does, and even if it was, it's not what you were intending.

Here's the docs for `permutations`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

> `itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)`
> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

We already know that `entry` only has 4 digits, so there are *no* permutations that have 6 digits. That's why your code doesn't work.

---

## Finding a solution

You said you want permutations like

```
X1234X 
1X234X
12X34X
```

where X are digits from 0 to 9. It's not clear to me whether there can be one number here or two. i.e. for `X1234X`, is `012345` valid?

I'm going to assume it is.

Let's write a function where we can give a line from the input, and we get out all the possible permutations with two additional numbers, each of which can be 0-9. Then we can call this function on each line, and save all the results to a file.

The obvious solution to me is to take the original field, add two digits to the end, and then find all the permutations of that.

I can use `itertools.product` to get all the options for the additional two digits:

```
i ❯ list(product("abc", repeat=2))
[('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('c', 'c')]
```

```
from itertools import product, permutations
from typing import Iterable

def get_expanded_permutations(entry: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    for x, y in product(range(10), repeat=2):
        # x, y are going to be (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), etc.
        new_entry = f"{entry}{x}{y}"
        
        # now we want all the permutations of that
        for perm in permutations(new_entry):
            yield "".join(perm)
```

Here's the first 10 items (there are 72000 in total):

```
i ❯ list(get_expanded_permutations("1234"))[:10]
['123400',
 '123400',
 '123040',
 '123004',
 '123040',
 '123004',
 '124300',
 '124300',
 '124030',
 '124003']
```

Let's assume we don't want duplicates, so can get rid of those by casting to and from a `set`:

```
results = list(set(get_expanded_permutations("1234")))
```

---

## My results with using ChatGPT

In the code that ChatGPT generated, the file is opened every time we want to write a new line. This isn't a great way of writing a file because there's quite a big overhead to opening the file.

But I also don't want to just wait until right at the end, in case there is an issue with reading an entry.

So instead I'm going to get all the results for each *entry*, and then write them all at once, and then move on the next entry.

So the final result would be:

```py
for entry in input_data:
    perms = set(get_expanded_permutations(entry))
    
    with open(self.output_file, 'a') as outfile:
        # write all of the permutations separated by newlines
        outfile.write("\n".join(perms))
        
        # plus another newline (otherwise the next entry won't be on a new line)
        outfile.write("\n")

    logfile.write(f"Generated permuations for entry: {entry} ({len(perms)})\n")
```

---

I don't know what you asked ChatGPT, but I gave it a go which you can find here: https://chat.openai.com/share/6b2391d2-b52e-466e-afe5-04725a9c3e33

Here's the code it generated, but this will only generate permutations like `1234XY`, so still not right.

My experience of using ChatGPT for writing code is that it never gets the right answer, and even if it gets close, it's not efficient.

```py
from itertools import permutations

def generate_permutations(num):
    # Convert the number to a string for permutation
    num_str = str(num)
    
    # Generate all permutations of the 4-digit number
    perms = permutations(num_str)
    
    # Store the permutations as a list of strings
    perm_list = [''.join(p) for p in perms]
    
    # Generate all 6-digit numbers with permutations and two additional digits
    six_digit_nums = []
    for perm in perm_list:
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                if i != int(perm[0]) or j != int(perm[1]):
                    six_digit_nums.append(int(perm + str(i) + str(j)))
    
    return six_digit_nums

# Example usage:
input_number = 1234  # Replace this with your 4-digit number
result = generate_permutations(input_number)
print(result)
```